# Find width of the child widget before build method is invoked again

Tags: flutter, dart, button, widget, renderbox

I am creating a custom button widget `MyButton` by composing `ElevatedButton` that will contains a `Text` widget as Child. It has a boolean `isLoading` property that will be used to configure the type of Button to build. When `isLoading = true` it will return a grey loading button having width **same as the width of text** provided prior to this loading button build. My question is how can I get the `width` of child `Text` widget before the build method is called or invoked again by setState, so that I can use that `width` to create the loading button of same size?

Loading Button will always be called after default Button has been built with child `Text` widget. (i.e. `isLoading` can be true only when widget is rebuilding not initially).

Here's the code:

```dart
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool isLoading;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  MyButton({Key key, @required this.text, @required this.isLoading, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  double _width; // Width of the [Text] child widget that will be used to get the [Container] of same width for loading button

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _width = 150;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant MyButton oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    /*
    Calculate the width....
     */
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // I want to get the width of this child
    Widget child = Text(
      widget.text,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    );
    if (widget.isLoading) {
      child = Container(
        height: 60,
        width: _width, // this should be same as [Text] width
        color: Colors.grey,
      );
    }
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: child,
      onPressed: !widget.isLoading ? widget.onPressed : null,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
          !widget.isLoading ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the demo of what I want to do but size of button when `isLoading = true` is absolute for now.

[image]

I have checked other posts and questions but could not find useful way to solve my usecase. Using `GlobalKey` is a solution but is not the recommended way and using `RenderObject` I was not able to solve this as in that case we can only get the intrinsic heights and widths of the parent.

I think there might be some other way to do this other than using GlobalKey and RenderObject.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it is using globalkey as the solution. I already mentioned about this that using GlobalKey is not always the recommended way.

Comment: Please read the question again. I have mentioned why I am not using this way.

Comment: Why don‘t you save yourself some trouble and use a predefined percentage of the screen size as your width? Like with MediaQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I can but I just wanted to make the loading button more dynamic by setting it the same width to get the same visual button dimensions.

Comment: So you want that when isLoading true you button should be blank and color should be grey and size also should be same?

Comment: @Diwyansh yes, I am creating a container for that but was not able to get size.

Comment: Please check answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. I have posted the solution that worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a Container for that I would prefer you just hide the text so that size of button will be same as previous. Try below code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: !widget.isLoading ? 1 : 0,
        child: Text(
          widget.text,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: !widget.isLoading ? widget.onPressed : null,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
          !widget.isLoading ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but its a kind on hack instead of actually calculating the dimensions.

Comment: It's as per your choice I have just provided the result for keeping same size of button in both situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the add `postFrameCallback` to WidgetBinding instance to get the size of the widget from the context inside `postFrameCallback`.

***NOTE: This may not be the efficient appraoch.***

Here's the code that worked in my case.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getWidth();
    _width = _width ?? 150;
  }

  void getWidth() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (context?.size is Size) {
        _width = context.size.width;
        print(context.size.toString());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant MyButton oldWidget) {
    getWidth();
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```